# How do I make nginx wait for my upstream service to start up in a Docker Swarm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, docker-swarm-mode

I deploy an nginx proxy service and a rails app service into a docker swarm. The nginx depends on the app in my docker-compose file.

My nginx.conf file directs traffic to my upstream app service (exposed on port 3000) like so (only showing the upstream part).

```
upstream puma {
  server app:3000;
}
```

My docker-compose file looks like so:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  app:
    image: my/rails-app:latest
    networks:
      - proxy

  web:
    image: my/nginx:1.11.9-alpine
    command: /bin/sh -c "nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      - proxy


networks:

  proxy:
    external: true
```

My host is setup to be swarm manager.

**This all works totally fine - there are no problems.**

**However**, even though I have a *depends* section in my docker-compose file - the app service may not be *completely* (?) ready by the time the nginx service starts up, so when the upstream service config part tries to DNS resolve "app:3000", it seems like it is not finding it completely. So when I visit my site, I find the following error message in my nginx logs:

```
2017/02/13 10:46:07 [error] 8#8: *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.255.0.3, server: www.mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.53.53:3000/", host: "preprod.local"
```

If I kill the docker container that is running the nginx service, and swarm reschedules it a moment later and it returns, if I then visit the same URL it works completely fine, and the request is passed successfully upstream to app:3000.

How can I prevent this from happening - where the startup timings are out by a little bit and at the time when nginx starts it can't yet properly resolve my swarm service called app:3000 - and instead it is attempting to pass the traffic onto an IP address ....

BTW - the same happens if I reboot my virtual machine - when docker (in swarm mode) brings up the services again - I can end up with the same problem. Restarting the nginx container solves the problem.

Answer (score 9):

I have figured out a way to do this - and this is to use the **HEALTHCHECK** section of the Dockerfile, or docker-compose file.

First of all, it seems as if the *depends_on* option isn't really used when deploying a stack with

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml mystack
```

Docker in swarm mode would just restart a service task if it wasn't able to start properly or failed for some other reason. So the *depends_on* options isn't really that useful.

So this is my solution in the end, and so far it works very well:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  app:
    image: my/rails-app:latest
    networks:
      - proxy

  web:
    image: my/nginx:1.11.9-alpine
    command: /bin/sh -c "nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - proxy
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "wget", "-qO-", "http://localhost/healthcheck"]
        interval: 5s
        timeout: 3s
        retries: 3

networks:

  proxy:
    external: true
```

So what I do is, from the nginx server I try access a route on my Rails app - I created one called /healthcheck and it returns a status code of 200.

So when I try and access it, and the result is a failure (the app server is not ready yet) - nginx will be restarted. Hopefully when it starts up again, the app server will be available, and the upstream app:3000 directive will do a correct DNS resolve.

So in this way I've "hacked" together the (missing) *depends_on* behaviour that could work in swarm mode.

Comment: you can also use ```restart``` option in ```deploy``` section. Then nginx container will restart while rails app is down. Btw, why do you check ```http://localhost/healthcheck``` url not ```http://app/healthcheck```? Will ```http://app/healthcheck``` be correct for healthcheck?

Comment: I haven't tries the http://app/healthcheck url - but the way I understand it, if I use http://localhost/healthcheck, then I'm hitting my Rails app via the nginx container - that's the connection I want to check. So it might be a bit more robust to use the localhost version. As the the restart option - I'm not sure how that would solve the problem - can you explain?

Comment: >  it might be a bit more robust to use the localhost version. 
I disagree with that. Though it works, it means several containers will be in a `exited` state before all gets set correctly. I hopped there was a solution to make sure nginx doesn't start *before* proxy is ready, but I guess there is not solution besides using `wait-for-it` or it's siblings.

Comment: That wouldn't really work if you had multiple services, plus doesn't allow for that to be used both locally and remotely when deploying

Answer (score 5):

*depends_on* option doesn't wait for the container to be ready, only until it's running. https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

There are two more options.

1. Starting from Compose v2.1 it is possible to include healthcheck in depends_on option. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#dependson
2. You can do the same using external tools like [dockerize](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize) or [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this image: https://hub.docker.com/r/atomgraph/nginx

It supports `$UPSTREAM_SERVER` and `$TIMEOUT` parameters (as environmental variables).